# Do XDEL, XADD and other Redis stream commands generate keyspace notifications?

Tags: redis

(The documentation is now updated with this information.) As of December, 2019, the Redis documentation on keyspace notifications (https://redis.io/topics/notifications) includes a lengthy list of Redis commands and the keyspace notifications that these commands fire. There are no stream operations (`XADD`, `XDEL`, `XTRIM` etc.) in the list. Is that because these operations do not cause keyspace notifications to fire, or is it because the list has not been updated to reflect the relatively new stream commands?

And if `XADD`, `XDEL` and `XTRIM`, specifically, do generate keyspace notifications, what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - all stream operations generate keyspace notifications. To enable the category either use the 't' flag, or the all-inclusive 'A', for the following:

- `XADD` generates an `xadd` event, possibly followed an `xtrim` event when used with the `MAXLEN` subcommand.
- `XDEL` generates a single `xdel` event even when multiple entries are are deleted.
- `XGROUP CREATE` generates an `xgroup-create` event.
- `XGROUP DELCONSUMER` generates an `xgroup-delconsumer` event.
- `XGROUP DESTROY` generates an `xgroup-destroy` event.
- `XGROUP SETID` generates an `xgroup-setid` event.
- `XSETID` generates an `xsetid` event.
- `XTRIM` generates an `xtrim` event.

Note: I've taken this as a cue to [update](https://github.com/antirez/redis-doc/pull/1215) the docs with the missing info - thanks for noticing and asking **@Dan Menes** :)